# How to ignore unwanted columns in CSV using FlatFileItemReader in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have run into an issue where I have a CSV file with 10 columns and need only selected columns to be mapped to my Java objects. However the CSV is header column and data position is fixed. So I know that only column 1 to 3 are useful to me and rest has to be ignored.
For eg: 
CSV is :
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10

I only need to have A1 till A3 columns to be mapped to my pojo.
I'm sure this is not the right way but I tried doing something like this but it isn't working. Spring batch is trying to map all column values to my pojo.

```
<property name="lineTokenizer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
        <property name="names" value="Name,Department,Age,,,,,,," />
    </bean>
</property>

<property name="fieldSetMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="EmployeeDO" />
    </bean>
```

I haven't explored all the features of spring batch but is there something that can be achieved easily? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`DelimitedLineTokenizer.setIncludedFields()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/DelimitedLineTokenizer.html#setIncludedFields-int:A-) should be the right call to solve your problem.

> The fields to include in the output by position (starting at 0). By
>   default all fields are included, but this property can be set to pick
>   out only a few fields from a larger set. Note that if field names are
>   provided, their number must match the number of included fields.